# Consider the advantages/disadvantages of tweeting your answers

Tags: discussion

The TSE software will tweet questions and answers on (I assume) a periodic basis. This is fine for people who follow TSE on Twitter, but may not reach *your* followers.

You can tweet using the 'share' button.

[image]

When you tweet questions, people can go "Hey, I know the answer to that" and then become valued community members.

And when you tweet answers, people can go "Hey, I need to read that, I'll go over there and read it..." and this drives up the site stats which in turn gives a higher Google ranking.

All good. I can't think of a disadvantage to tweeting out your stuff (can you?) and there are lots of advantages.

Are there any aspects where tweeting your stuff results in a disadvantage?

Comment: The comments I get when I tweet the toilet questions :/

Comment: Clearly, once we leave TSE not everybody is an adult anymore …

Comment: I'm one of these privacy-crazers and like to keep my twitter (not that I'd use it other than complaining to companies) and SE separate.

Comment: @mts haha, I'm with you on that one. The only reason I even have a twitter is that sometimes it's the most convenient way to get a quick answer to questions from an airline when the answer isn't on their website.